# Use Word Find-Replace to insert missing commas?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

**What I have**: `[any-word] &`

**What I want**: `[any-word], &`

(notice the comma after the ampersand)

**Question**

Using Word, I can find what I have using this expression:

```
([a-z]>)( {1,})(&)
```

What is the expression get what I want; i.e, to insert a comma and not change the text?

If it's not possible to do this with Word, then what can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your search string, you have used round brackets `(` `)` to mark three expressions:

```
([a-z]>)( {1,})(&)
```

In your replacement string, the characters found to match each of these can be identified by `\n`, where `n` is the expression number.

So your replacement string becomes:

```
\1,\2\3
```

In fact there was no need to mark the blanks and ampersand separately, so it's simpler to replace:

```
([a-z]>)( {1,}&)
```

with:

```
\1,\2
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @AFH is spot on. I am posting this as an extension to his answer to be sure I understand how to interpret the expressions. I did not edit my original post, because my follow-on question needs to be seen in context with @AFH's answer.

**My understanding and what perplexes me**

In the **Find** expression the opening and closing parens signal a search unit, or group with an *implied* number to show sequence:

```
([a-z]>)( {1,}&)
Group 1  Group 2
```

The meaning is Find:

- In group 1, find any word that ends with a lowercase letter a-z.
- In group 2, find one space and an ampersand.

In the **Replace** expression, the slashes indicate what to do with each group:

```
\1,\2
```

- Replace group 1 "as is" plus insert a comma immediately after the letter.
- Replace group 2 "as is" (do not make any changes)

So ... I understand the comma in the replacement expression, but the purpose of the comma in the find expression { 1,} is not self-evident to me.

*Notes*

- For anyone reading this post who is new to (or rusty with) Word Find/Replace, wildcards must be ON.
- By understanding the expression, I hope to be able to replicate the solution to other simple punctuation problems.

Comment: I didn't go into this detail, because your use of brackets suggested that you already some understanding of the Regular Expressions that Word uses. The group `{m,n}` means "between **m** and **n** occurrences of previous match pattern. If `m` is omitted, then there is no lower limit (ie between **0** and **n** occurrences); while if `n` is omitted then there is no upper limit (ie **m** or more occurrences). In your case the match pattern is a space, so `( {1,}&)` matches one or more spaces followed by ampersand (as the second match expression).